# Picture Library Slideshow webpart not playing?

Tags: content-editor-web-part, picture-library

I recently have used picture Library Slideshow webpart but the option for pause and play is not working. the fast forwards are working though. What can be the cause for this?

Comment: what you mean by picture Library Slideshow webpart in CEWP

Comment: did you try this in IE?

Comment: is any folder added in the picture library

Comment: No folder ony images . Earlier in every browser it was working but now that play button is not working specifically

Comment: What's your SharePoint version?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Sharepoint 365:

According to Microsoft

> In a recent update to Office 365 that is currently being deployed, the
> ability to automatically switch to new images is being deprecated for
> libraries that do not have a Content Delivery Network (CDN) enabled.
> This means that the AutoPlay functionality for existing websites will
> no longer function for Picture Library Slideshow web parts.

The full information from Microsoft can be found [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/troubleshoot/web-parts/non-cdn-enabled-picture-library-slideshow-web-part-no-longer-switches-automatically-to-new-images)

To use the CDN together with the Picture Library Slideshow web part, your SharePoint Online tenant administrator must enable the CDN within your Office 365 tenancy.

You can find the [steps to enable CDN within tenancy here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180202220410/https://dev.office.com/blogs/general-availability-of-office-365-cdn)

But to help in case of link death here is the pertinent information

> Using Office 365 CDN in SharePoint Online
> Here are the steps to get started with the Office 365 CDN.
>
> Make sure that you are using the latest version of SharePoint Online
> Management Shell You can download SharePoint Online Management Shell
> from following link:
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588
>
> Connect to your SharePoint Online tenant with PowerShell
>
> Connect-SPOService -Url https://vesaj-admin.sharepoint.com
>
> Get status of the CDN settings from tenant level
>
> Get-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType Public / Private
>
> Enable CDN in the tenant
>
> Set-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType Public / Private ...
>
> Public CDN enabled locations:
> */MASTERPAGE
> */STYLE LIBRARY
>
> Disable CDN in the tenant
>
> Set-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType Public / Private -Enable $false
>
> Get default configuration of your public CDN settings
>
> Get-SPOTenantCdnPolicies -CdnType Public ...
>
> Key Value   --- -----   IncludeFileExtensions
> CSS,EOT,GIF,ICO,JPEG,JPG,JS,MAP,PNG,SVG,TTF,WOFF
> ExcludeRestrictedSiteClassifications   ExcludeIfNoScriptDisabled False
>
> Add new CDN origin
>
> Add-SPOTenantCdnOrigin -CdnType Public -OriginUrl sites/cdn/cdn ...
>
> Public CDN enabled locations:
> */MASTERPAGE
> */STYLE LIBRARY SITES/CDN/CDN (configuration pending)
>
> See the list of CDN origins
>
> Get-SPOTenantCdnOrigins -CdnType Public ...
>
> */MASTERPAGE
> */STYLE LIBRARY SITES/CDN/CDN
>
> Remove CDN origin
>
> Remove-SPOTenantCdnOrigin -CdnType Public -OriginUrl sites/cdn/cdn ...
>
> Public CDN enabled locations:
> */MASTERPAGE
> */STYLE LIBRARY